Integration Monit with Amazon SES using IAM instance profile
Monit documentation has no information about this integration. I already set the "mailserver" config in monitrc file like below.
set mailserver email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Getting the error in monit log:
Mail: Mailserver response error -- 530 Authentication required
I am already able to send email in the same EC2 since the instance has IAM instance profile with SES permissions.
I don't want to do it with smtp credentials stored in the monitrc file like the explanation in monit documentation. If there is no way, I will do it with aws-cli in a shell and call this shell file in monit.
Does anyone have any ideas about Monit - AWS SES with Instance profile integration?

I know nothinng about AWS, but some about monit - so I keep this a acomment instead of an answer ^^. Keep in mind that monit's config file is "secure by default" (see https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/src/52b2a2ffa2f8b3a3e8a51514c1f3d8c291da4206/src/file.c?at=master#lines-157:179 ). To lift the limitations of the default mail, I implemented a "fakeSMTP-Server" to handle my monit's mails and send them through slack, PushBullet, Telegram, etc. see https://github.com/boppy/nitmo.fakesmtp

Thanks boppy, i solved it calling aws-cli to delegate sending mail. Aws-cli does not require SMTP credentials if the ec2 has required iam instance profile. The disadvantage of not having a mailserver in monit is the loss of native alert feature.. Keeping in my mind your project, thanks.

Btw, the repo owner reported that it is not possible directly. https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/1104/how-to-integrate-monit-with-aws-ses-using

The answer from Tildeslash.

No, you need to set credentials for the SMTP.
Alternatively you can use custom program for alert notification (e.g.
using aws-cli), see example for Slack and Pushover:
https://mmonit.com/wiki/Notification/Notification

Like suggested by boppy you can use a notify script to send alert/alarms, in Monit or M/Monit.
For documentation purpose only,
Lutz
